# Young adult vampire novel with a female vampire hunter and her two friends, all orphaned

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, vampire

This was a young adult vampire book about a girl who is a vampire hunter with her two other friends. They are trained by a man who is an older hunter.

All of their parents were killed when they were younger and the main girl was raised by her grandmother. The other male friend was raised by his mum but she is kinda out of it and the third friend is a female who is raised by the older hunter. The third female is somewhat psychic.

The male lead is a vampire who's very old and is much stronger than most other vampires. They both are linked.

In the book they are attacked by the vampire's old friend who's pretty crazy.
At the end of the book they find out he is a vampire when he saves her from the crazy vampire.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if that helps you refine your question. :) Good start!

Comment: Whoever wrote this had clearly watched a whole bunch of episodes of Buffy

Comment: Just to be clear, the old vampire male lead is not one of her two friends, or the older hunter?

Comment: And when did the fellow who was raised by his mum become orphaned?

Comment: Female vampire hunter orphan girls are a pretty common trope; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17704479-the-breathing-ghosts

Comment: They were all orphaned at a very young age but the male friends mother ran away with the children while the parents all died. The older hunter is not one of the three friends, he is the trainer